# One header on all pages (php)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

i want one header on All pages but this Code **only** working on localhost but not working on Hosting

```
<?php include_once("header.php");?>
```

thanks

Comment: Have you triple-checked your path is correct? Is "header.php" in the same directory as the file on which it is intended to be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more CodeIgniter orientated answer, I would suggest to move your header in to your templates/views section of CI. From there, I would do the following in your controller:

```
$this->load->view('header', $header); //Nav Bar
$this->load->view('clients/overview', $data); //Detailed Page View
$this->load->view('footer'); //Tidy Up with Footer etc
```

Similar can be achieved in CakePHP.